# How to add authentication method to already existing Okta to ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net, okta-api

I have ASP.NET project with working Okta authentication set up, but I need to allow user to authenticate by another service, which also uses JWT. What are best practises to do it?
Okta authentication was set up using [this guid](https://developer.okta.com/quickstart-fragments/dotnet/aspnet4-implicit/#configure-the-middleware), so Startap.cs has this method:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseOktaWebApi(new OktaWebApiOptions()
    {
        OktaDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:OktaDomain"],
    });
}
```

I've already tried using [this guid](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/26/decode-jwt-in-csharp-for-authorization), but could not make it work because it gets error

> Error CS1061  'AuthenticationBuilder' does not contain a definition for
>   'AddOpenIdConnect' and no accessible extension method
>   'AddOpenIdConnect' accepting a first argument of type
>   'AuthenticationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

For code

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "OpenIdConnect";
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>{}); // error is thrown here
```

Answer (score 0):

After lots of googling and trying to find a solution I have created an AuthorizeAttribute and overrode IsAuthorized method:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // here we can check if default (in my case Okta) authorization allowed access for request
        if (base.IsAuthorized(actionContext))
        {
            return true;
        }
        // add some logic and return true or false depending on if access is allowed or not
        return false;
    }
}
```